# Gradle Error - "BUILD FAILED: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath' "

Tags: gradle

I am trying to compile a Minecraft mod that I downloaded from Github using Gradle. It errors halfway through with this error:
[Command Line Gradle Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ncF8.png)

I am guessing I have to go into my routers firewall and allow Gradle to download from repo1.maven.org. I just don't know how to do that, and I don't want to mess anything up and break anything because I guess.
How do I do this? If I am wrong about the problem, can you please help me find the correct solution?

Comment: this project seems not maintained anymore.. the maven repo specified in the project homepage does not contain this artifefact : https://repo.elytradev.com/com/elytradev/    (see https://github.com/elytra/Mirage )

Comment: It also had minecraftforge.net in it. Is there anyway to allow that?